# flash player not working under xvfb

Tags: flash, xvfb

Flash player not working in firefox (centos 5.5 x64) that run with selenium under XVFB. I'm getting just black screen in place where flash should be visible.

Tried both 32 and 64 versions.

May you suggest anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this from a terminal, make sure you installed the correct Flash player plugin and not Flash itself. If you were using Ubuntu, you would run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

Also, what version of Firefox are you running? If you are running 3.0, make sure to open defaults/preferences/firefox.js and make sure you don't have anything here that would be stopping Flash.